# Zapier scripting - for loops

Tags: javascript, zapier

I cant seem to figure this out.  Here is my working JSfiddle code that sends data to console perfectly.  I know my zapier app is passing authentication.  I'm getting a 200-success if I just return

```
var stuff = 
{
    "uri":"some URL here",
    "action":"EXPORT",
    "result":
    {
        "column_order":["Name","email","TimeStamp"],
            "rows":[
                ["ted2","ted2@example.com","06 Feb, 2018 04:37:16"],
                ["jimf","jimf@example.com","06 Feb, 2018 19:03:39"]
                ]
    }
};

var results2 = [];

for (var j = 0; j < stuff.result.rows.length; j++)
{
    var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.result.column_order.length; i++)
{
     result['"' + stuff.result.column_order[i] + '"'] = stuff.result.rows[j][i];

  }
  results2.push(result);
}

 console.log(results2);
```

It spits out:

```
{
  "Name": "ted2",
  "email": "ted2@example.com",
  "TimeStamp": "06 Feb, 2018 04:37:16"
}{
  "Name": "jimf",
  "email": "jimf@example.com",
  "TimeStamp": "06 Feb, 2018 19:03:39"
}
```

Now if I try to convert this to a Zapier Post POLL function, I keep getting errors: Javascript Exception: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined`.

Here is my Zapier Post Poll function.  What am I missing?  For loops just wont work the same.

```
email_post_poll: function(bundle){
  var response = z.JSON.parse(bundle.response.content);
  var results2 = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < response.result.rows.length; j++)
      {
         var result = {};
         for (var i = 0; i < response.result.column_order.length; i++)
        {
         result['"' + response.result.column_order[i] + '"'] = response.rows[j][i];

        }
        results2.push(result);
  }
   return results2 || [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Your issue is in the for loop, you're calling `= response.rows[j][i]`, which should be `= response.result.rows[j][i]`. If that doesn't clear it up, I'd suggest using `console.log` to make sure you know what is actually coming in the response.

As a side note, arrays are truthy in js, so `results2 || []` will never return the empty array on the right.

Comment: Good catch.  I'e been going back and forth on the dot notation and missed that.  It didn't fix it though.  The issue is with the very first "For" line.  I know it's hanging up on that because if I keep changing the notation, the error changes.  I tried inserting a console.log(response) right before the loop and nothing appears.  I'm not getting a console dump.I am using web builder as this should be pretty easy.  In the top section where I have my variable "stuff =" from the working Jsfiddle is my API response in "Request Logs" so the dot notation sould be the same?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.  bundle.response.content had a parent array of "response" on top of everything.  So i actually had to call "response.response." for everything.  Using the console.log suggestion from Dave helped me solve this but you can only see the console log inside of the scripting tool and then "Bundle logs".  Just a learning curve for the platform i guess.

```
email_post_poll: function(bundle){
  var response = z.JSON.parse(bundle.response.content);
  var results2 = [];
  console.log(response.response.result.rows.length);

    for (var j = 0; j < response.response.result.rows.length; j++)
      {
         var results3 = {};
         for (var i = 0; i < response.response.result.column_order.length; i++)
        {
         results3['"' + response.response.result.column_order[i] + '"'] = response.response.result.rows[j][i];

        }
        results2.push(results3);
  }
  return results2;
```

Comment: Now that it's working it may not be worth changing, but the new CLI is way better for this stuff if you have some development chops! Something to keep in mind for the future

Comment: I've played around with CLI builder. Far more robust I agree. This app I just built was for a SUPER common web platform with extremely good API but no Zapier triggers. All I needed was just this one post_poll function to manipulate the json response and my app and integration is complete.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!